# Error deleting blob container ' (my container name) ': details

Tags: azure, azure-storage

i can't delete it, i thought there are no any links between this storage

here's the screenshot

[image]

it said remove the container

[image]

i try to delete the container, but it said there is a lease
and there is no other services work,

but i don't understand,anyone help?

Comment: You get this error message *because* there is still a reference between your blob and a disk or image.  Check again using the Azure Portal and make sure you don't have anything referencing that blob.

Comment: No any reference, i check again, and may i ask, where's the blob exists?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer

[Here to see the answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/10c60757-b47f-4462-9518-4bddcec690dc)
thanks to navcode in msdn

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after starting (or attempting to start) several virtual machines.  After you terminate the virtual machine the disk image still remains. You can see it in the storage container but not delete it from there because it is still "leased".

Check under virtual machines and click the "disk" link as per this image:

[image: azure virtual machin disks]

You can delete the disk image from there.  Make sure you don't delete an image for a virtual machine you may need some day.